# Down Slider from the list

Tags: javascript, css, titanium

I am a newbie on Appcelerator Titanium and practicing by developing some mobile apps and came across a situation and need some help.

I have a list of items, which displays from a table and on clicking any item, there should be a bigger space below slides down from clicked item for some entry fields. I am attaching a sample, basically from fig 1, when touched (ofcourse in mobile) it should expand like in fig 2.

Thanks.
[image: Fig1][image: Fig2]

Comment: Titanium Mobile? iOS? Android? Web? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I am sorry it is Titanium Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky with Titanum. As it looks it's a row-based approach. So first you should decide to use a `TableView`

```
var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  width: Ti.UI.FILL,
  height: Ti.UI.FILL,
});
```

Then you need to add the rows from the left screen. These are simple rows.

```
var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
  var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow(...);
  // do some layout, add some views here
  rows.push(row);
}
// add to table view
tableView.data = [rows];
```

Then you need to apply a 'click' listener.

```
var isOpen = false; // is already one element clicked and opened?
var whichIsOpen = undefined; // if yes, which one (index of clicked element)?
tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(isOpen && e.index === whichIsOpen) {
    tableView.deleteRow(whichIsOpen+1);
    isOpen = false;
    return;
  }
  if(isOpen && e.index === whichIsOpen + 1) {
    return;
  }
  tableView.deleteRow(whichIsOpen+1);
  var specialRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow(...); // row which contains the elements of the right screen
  var newIndex = e.index > whichIsOpen ? e.index : e.index + 1; // because removed one
  tableView.insertRowAfter(newIndex-1, specialRow);
  whichIsOpen = newIndex;
})
```

In this solution you can only open one element at the same time. I typed this from my head, i didn't test. So it's up to you!

Comment: Thanks its working... one quick question, just give me some idea how do we do the same thing using, javascript and CSS.

Comment: with js and css you could simply hide and show the additional rows. this is of course an easier solution. 1. Provide all the rows and hide every second row. 2. After clicking on a visible row, the additional rows is shown. But when this is only used for mobile web apps you shouldn't use Titanium. Use something like jQuery.

Comment: Great Thanks VVoo. Appreciate your help.